# enum in Singleton cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, enums, cocos2d-iphone

What do you recommend me if I have two layers (which are added to a `parallaxNode`) and on each layers I've added sprites which I want to restrict the order that the player won't be able to remove sprite5 until it removes first the previous ones: sprite1, sprite2, sprite3 and sprite4 and so one.
I'm using [Juan's example](http://juanmunozar.blogspot.com/2009/02/cocos2d-iphone-dynamically-touch.html) for dynamically touch detection

What will be the dynamical option for this?

UPDATE:

```
if([sprite tag] == tag_collection_1 && [sprite GetCanTrack]) {

//Set others to NO & call remove sprite method
[[TSprite FindByTag:tag_collection_number] SetCanTrack:NO];
[self removeSpriteMethod:touchLocation];
} else if ([sprite tag] == tag_collection_number && [sprite GetCanTrack]) {
// and so on
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a fifo stack implementation. If you want to remove the sprite, you first check if it's at the bottom of the stack and when you do remove it, you pop it from the stack as well. Practically you will have an NSMutableArray and look at the first item if the object is in that position before you remove it. If you have added 1,2,3,4,5 in that order and want only to be able to remove them in the same order you check if the object you are trying to remove is at index 0 in the array first.

Comment: Have you take a look the the [Juan's example](http://juanmunozar.blogspot.com/2009/02/cocos2d-iphone-dynamically-touch.html)? wouldn't be much easier to user `SetCanTrack:BOOL` method for that?

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't understand the question. I guess you want to do setCanTrack:NO for all and then setCanTrack:YES to 2 if 1 is tracked and so on. Well the solution should be similar, just have them in the array and when first object is tracked you do setCanTracked:YES for [array objectAtIndex:[array indexOfObject:current]+1].